# ¿Como uso .get en Selenium? Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

estoy haciendo un programa y necesito abrir una pagina web desde python, estoy utilizando el modulo de selenium. Este es el código :

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser=webdriver.Chrome
browser.get("https://facebook.com")
```

El problema es que cuando lo pruebo me aparece este error en la consola :

```
TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'url'
```

Pero según yo si estoy poniendo el argumento de URL.
¿Qué es lo que me hace falta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al inicializar `browser` te faltaron los paréntesis tras el nombre de la clase, es decir, debería ser así:

```
browser=webdriver.Chrome()
```

De este modo se crea un objeto, y la variable `browser` sería una referencia a ese nuevo objeto creado.

Tal como tú lo tenías, en cambio:

```
browser=webdriver.Chrome
```

la variable `browser` sería una referencia *a la clase*, en lugar de serlo a un objeto, por lo que no podría funcionar correctamente al no existir un objeto adecuadamente inicializado.

En cuanto a explicar el extraño error que te decía que faltaba la `url`, cuando claramente la estabas pasando, se debe a lo siguiente. Al intentar invocar el método `browser.get()`, ya que `browser` referenciaba una clase en lugar de un objeto, no estabas invocando un método del objeto, sino un método de la clase. En las clases los métodos se declaran con un primer parámetro extra, `self`, que cuando haces la invocación a través de un objeto Python rellena automáticamente. En este caso, sin embargo, al invocarlo a través de la clase, Python esperaba dos parámetros, `self` y `url` y sólo le pasabas uno, por eso el error te decía que faltaba el segundo.

Answer (score 0):

También deberías instalar el chromedriver para que te funcionara, puedes encontrar la documentación [aquí](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/).

Una vez lo instales deberas escribir esto:

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome(geckodriver = PATH)
```

Y el path es la ruta donde instalas el chromedriver.